# Unity 5 Virtual Reality Supported: Text shimmering / aliasing in GearVR

Tags: unity

I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out but have not come up with a conclusion. I'd appreciate if anyone has experienced the same and any thoughts.

Basically, I'm noticing that if I have a scene with text in it (world canvas and UI text component), when I build for GearVR with Unity's VR support, the text aliases like crazy. To be honest I'm not even sure 100% if it is plain old aliasing. The text just constantly shimmers.

I tried moving things around in case it was z fighting but it seems it is not.

I tried enabling anti aliasing from the quality settings and neither does it seem to make a difference.

I tried tweaking the Canvas Scaler Dynamic and Reference pixels/unit settings (which are not entirely clear to me from the docs btw). But at most, I was able to make the text slightly blurry as mentioned in the Unity VR guide and it barely helps.

I tried making the canvas and text huge and then scaling the canvas down to 0.05.

finally I tried making my text bold and bigger. And that seemed to mitigate the shimmering to a certain extent but not 100%.

But I've seen Unity apps for GearVR that don't exhibit this shimmering issue. So I am wondering what else might I be missing. I'm on 5.3.3.p3 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Morgen. Unfortunatly I can't offer a solution or advice. But my experiences are that GearVR seems to have a big problem with text readability/sharpness. I toyed around with a small selfmade app and built it for cardboard and GearVr. On the GearVR texts were barely readable while on Cardboard the text was perfectly clear. Only thing changed has been the cardboard/occulus plugin. In my opinion you will have to dig into the "performance optimizations" hidden in the VR support. Back then there were unchangeable qualiity settings modifications.

Comment: Try lowering the font size and increasing the scale of the Text UI object.

Comment: A year and a half later, any insight? Working on a project now that has this problem, and not just text, but "text-like" objects: pretty much any texture where there are thin, vertical elements, including the outline edge on buttons.